# Index out of range with geoplot

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, geopandas, kernel-density, geoplot

I am trying to create a KDE plot to show the geographic density of each crime category. The dataset is the [Philadelphia Crime Incidents](https://metadata.phila.gov/#home/datasetdetails/5543868920583086178c4f8e/representationdetails/570e7621c03327dc14f4b68d/) and the [Philadelphia Police District Boundaries](https://metadata.phila.gov/#home/datasetdetails/5543866f20583086178c4f24/representationdetails/55438ab79b989a05172d0d5b/).

```
import geopandas as gpd
import geoplot as gplt

gdf = data.copy()
gdf['Coordinates'] = list(zip(gdf.point_x, gdf.point_y))
gdf.Coordinates = gdf.Coordinates.apply(Point)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    gdf,
    geometry='Coordinates',
    crs="epsg:4326"
)

# GDF of crime incidents
crime_data = gdf.loc[gdf["text_general_code"] == 'Thefts']

# Boundaries of the region
land = pd_boundary.unary_union
land = gpd.GeoDataFrame(gpd.GeoSeries(land), columns=["geometry"])
land = land.set_geometry("geometry")
land.crs = "epsg:4326"
```

When I try to draw a KDE plot, I am unusually getting `IndexError: index out of range`.
I have tried checking for null values and also searched online for probable cause but didn't help.

```
ax = gplt.polyplot(land)
gplt.kdeplot(
    crime_data,
    ax=ax
)
```

Any ideas on how to debug would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I test your code on an example data and was able to reproduce your issue. If I removed all `na` values from `data` I was able to make the figure. So you can insert these lines of code before making the `gpd.GeoDataFrame`:

```
data_na = data.dropna(axis=0)
gdf = data_na.copy()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works, but I also lost some data because of dropping the `na` values resulting in empty visualizations. Improving upon your idea, I used `is_empty` on the geometry column to remove the empty geometry values.